# Display MySQL Data in a Label - Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, mysql

I have some code here that connects to my Mysql database. It checks your username and password and if your login was successful and it retrieves the phone number under that account. How would the SQL Query look like for retrieving the phone number once connected? Then how would I be able to display that phone number on a label?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tutorial, should cover most of what you would need to know about connecting to MySQL, executing queries and displaying results:

[VBMySQL Tutorial - Part 4](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4)

There are a number of other tutorials on that site, should get you going.

If part 4 gets into too much depth too quickly, [check out part 1 first](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: I don't think those tutorials answer my questions.

Comment: You're asking how to query a database, and display data on a label in VB.NET.  Those tutorials cover that in detail.  Read the part that titled: Retrieving the User ID With A Parameterized Query.  And rather than a UserID returned, you'd return the PhoneNumber, set it to a String.  Then myControl.Text = PhoneNumber.

Answer (score 1):

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

```
string strCon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConString"];
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand com;
public string strPKDataValue;
public SqlDataReader dr;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
}
```

protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        com = new SqlCommand("select * from student", con);
        con.Open();

```
    try
    {
        dr = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Label9.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["stuid"]);

            }
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error :" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

}